# QAF opensource integration with ALM

Tags: alm, qaf

I want to update test results from Qmetry to ALM test set. Can anyone share the code if already implemented it.

Thanks,
Hidayath

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately alm rest API is not available  publicly and available with alm instance only. So each organization who use alm has code inside their organization which may not be available as open source out side organization. You can either ask alm support team to work with QAF team to have open source integration support or use ALM rest API and implement [result updator](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/integration_with_other_tools.html) for your organization.